# adding / to end of URL

Tags: javascript, html, .net, model-view-controller

Though fluent in the business logic layer (c#), I am rusty with javscript.

**What would be a safer way of appending "/" to the end of a string, if and only if it does not end with "/" ?**

Currently, I have:

```
            if (entityId != undefined) {
                noteUrl = window.parent.serverUrl;
                if (noteUrl.substring(noteUrl.length - 1) != "/") {
                    noteUrl += "/";
                }
```

Comment: [`if (!noteUrl.endsWith("/")) {...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith) Don't know what you mean by "safer", but I think this is a little nicer.

Answer (score 1):

Using a ternary expression:

```
noteUrl += noteUrl.endsWith("/") ? "" : "/";
```

Answer (score 1):

endsWith returns a bool true or false.

```
if ( !noteUrl.endsWith("/") )
 noteUrl += "/"
```

w3schools is always useful

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_endswith.asp